# flatten vectors in a map

Tags: c++11, dictionary, vector, constants

In C++, I have a `map < int, vector < double > >` or `map < int, vector < some_Struct > >`, I need to concatenate the vectors in this map and return the result.

The first version of the function is below:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>

vector < double >
flattenRecords(const map < int, vector < double > > & selected, int num_kept_reps)
{
  vector < double > records;
  int cnt = 0;
  for (auto it = selected.begin(); it != selected.end(); ++it) {
    records.insert(records.end(),
                   make_move_iterator(it->second.begin()),
                   make_move_iterator(it->second.end()));
    cnt += 1;
    if (cnt >= num_kept_reps)
    break;
  }
  return records;
}
```

I know this is not what I intended to do, because I would like to keep the data in the `map`, and thus should not use `make_move_iterator`.

The codes can compile using g++ (GCC) 4.4.7 with the `-std=c++0x` flag.

So here is the question, I declare the `map` to be `const`, what happens when I try to use something like `std::move` to the `vector` in the `map`?

My second version is to use:

```
copy(it->second.begin(), it->second.end(), back_inserter(records));
```

I guess this does what I intend to do.

I am quite new to C++. The STL gives me a feeling of coding in python so I would like to try it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of using make_move_iterator(Iterator), just use Iterator if you would not like to move the elements. Eg:

```
records.insert(records.end(), it->second.begin(), it->second.end());
```

Your second version, as you guess, does indeed what you try to achieve.
Regarding your question about std::move on a const map, the std::move won't do anything in such a case. Since std::move is unconditional cast to rvalue, it'll cast the element to a const reference to an rvalue. Because it's const it'll match the lvalue ctor (copy ctor in this case), and not the move (copy) ctor.

Eg:

```
const std::string s1 = "Test";
const std::string s2 = std::move(s1);
```

This will invoke the copy constructor of std::string, not the move constructor. Hence, it'll do a copy, not a move.

This will do a move:

```
std::string s1 = "Test";
const std::string s2 = std::move(s1);
```

The s2 parameter in both examples does not have to be const. It makes no difference regarding the copy/move.

Answer (score 1):

There is a 'pythonic' alternative, which you may like if you come from Python, using lambda and a "mapped-reduce" function

```
std::vector<double> merged = std::accumulate(selected.begin(),
                selected.end(),
                std::vector<double>(),
                [](const std::vector<double>& a, std::vector<double>& b)
                    {
                           std::vector<double> result(a);
                           std::copy(b.begin(), b.end(), std::back_inserter(result));
                           return result;
                    });
                );
```

`std::move` does not actually move data. It casts a reference to a r-value reference, which, if non-const, is a "movable" data type that move constructors can use. But it will never remove a const type qualifier, so using `std::move` on a const reference will not cast it to a movable type.